# How to Redirect in .htaccess New Issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is what i have done in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^takeshiyashima.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.takeshiyashima.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /us/my-blog\?catid=1&id=432(.*)\:(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /us/my-blog/others/432-petrodollar-system-inevitable-economic-collapse-and-possibility-of-world-war-iii? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /tw\?catid=0&id=539(.*)\:(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /tw/about-takeshi? [R=301,L]
```

i want to redirect the catid and id to another links where the post is active and Google can crawl.

```
RewriteRule ^ /us/my-blog/others/432-petrodollar-system-inevitable-economic-collapse-and-possibility-of-world-war-iii? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /tw\?catid=0&id=539(.*)\:(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /tw/about-takeshi? [R=301,L]
```

In this two redirection first one worked perfectly but i can't redirect the last one. I have similar more crawl error :

```
http://www.takeshiyashima.com/ja/resources?id=366:video-clip 
http://www.takeshiyashima.com/ja/resources?id=364:mortgage-reset-second-big-wave 
http://www.takeshiyashima.com/us/my-blog/65-investment?catid=230&id=230:wealth-cycle9 
http://www.takeshiyashima.com/us/resources?catid=72&id=354:fractional-reserve-banking 
http://www.takeshiyashima.com/en/?start=40
```

I can't fix this. May be this will make sense. If anyone know this please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using `THE_REQUEST` if you don't really need to. In your case using `QUERY_STRING` is most probably better suited.

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^catid=0&id=539:.+
RewriteRule ^tw$ /tw/about-takeshi? [R=301,L]
```

And in case the language prefix is the only difference in the localized URL, then you could easily match it in a single rule

```
RewriteRule ^(tw|ja|us|en)$ /$1/about-takeshi? [R=307,L]
```

However, depending on how many different URLs you need to redirect, it might even be better suited to redirect on application level, ie let the application evaluate the URL, retrieve the necessary details for the new URL (category and title) from the database, and redirect appropriately.

And last but not least this is nothing that has't been explained over and over again before, so I'd recommend using the search and checking [**the docs**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to get used to how rewriting works.

Comment: hello @ndm thank you for your answer, But unfortunately your rules are not working. Do you have any different ideas.

Comment: @graphicdesigner Can I assume that they do work now, considering that you've accepted the answer?

Comment: Hi @ndm I just accepted your answer for your help actually. `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /tw\?catid=0&id=539(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /tw/about-takeshi? [R=301,L]` This rules worked at last. Please vote me. Thank you.